# Best classification technique for following kind of data set

Tags: classification, clustering, k-means, pca, hierarchical-data-format

I have a large table where each record or row represents a single salesperson, and there are 50 columns or dimensions where each column represents one of 50 products potentially sold by any given salesperson, with one final column representing their total compensation as a percentile of their salesperson peers.
The values within each column range from 0 to 100, reflective of the salesperson's percentile performance in sales for that product, and then in the final column, percentile in total compensation.

e.g.

prodA | prodB | prodC | prodD | ... | prodAW | prodAX | comp

0 | 93 | 0 | 87 | ... | 73 | 0 | 88

100 | 0 | 44 | 0 | ... | 99 | 63 | 67

88 | 91 | 0 | 89 | ... | 85 | 88 | 24

...

assume there are at least 50K records (i.e. 50K salespeople)

If the value in any of the 50 columns equals 0, it means the salesperson didn't sell any of the given product. Using the last row in the example table above
that salesperson may have been 88th percentile in terms of sales of product A, and 91st percentile in sales of product B, they are only 24th percentile in terms of total salesperson compensation (see last column).
What approach would be best to categorize and classify natural groupings of salespeople?  Would I use something like a k-means clustering?

TL;DR: What is the best approach for classifying/clustering/categorizing salespeople into appropriate groups?

Comment: what's the goal of this clustering attempt? clustering can be adjusted to produce basically any result imaginable, so you need to be very clear on what you ultimately are trying to achieve.

Comment: Let's say in this case, the objective is trying to identify whether there are any natural "specialties" of product sales (product sale combos).  Do those who excel in selling one product or group typically do so in another.  Are there specific combinations of strong sales performance that lead to better performance in total compensation?  Is success in sales of a particular product most predictive

Comment: categroization approach may help in developing specific profiles of persons we want to recruit given our objectives to grow specifc (or specific combinations of) products.  does that help clarify at all?